# overriding Cart.php class doesn't work in prestashop

Tags: php, overriding, prestashop

I am try to override the default Cart.php class. I put my Cart.php in override/classes/Cart.php. but It doesn't make any changes in the output.

```
<?php
class Cart extends CartCore
{
print_r("sample test override");
die();
}
?>
```

my cart.php code is like above. Can anyone help me, is there any other additional steps needed to override?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant perform any actions outside of methods in classes

```
<?php
class Cart extends CartCore
{
    public function foo()
    {
        print("sample test override");
        die();
    }
}

$cart = new Cart();

$cart->foo();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should delete the file "class_index.php" in cache folder.